# Why can't I see default icon in the action bar?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-launcher

I thought I could be able to display the icon on the action bar, but as you can see it's no working, where's the problem?
Maybe it depends on the compiledSdkVersion.

My manifest is the default one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fulvio.bitsandpizzas">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My build.gradle:

```
[![android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.fulvio.bitsandpizzas"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: \['*.jar'\])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

[image: Android Main Action screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon is not showed in the `Toolbar` (the new `ActionBar`) by default in the newest versions of Android and if you put it manually it won't follow the material design guidelines:

https://material.io

If you want to put it anyway, you could create a toolbar.xml with your `AppBar` and custom `Toolbar` and use it in activities including your toolbar layout :

```
<include layout="@layout/your_layout">
```

Comment: I'm using Theme.AppCompat.Light as styles, and AppCompatActivity as activity

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your `onCreate` Method of `Activity`.

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

or if you using SupportActionBar then,

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way go to `MainActivity.java` and paste this code

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);        
}
```